# Why application stop is greater than GC Time

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

When we analyse gc logs produced by jvm via command line options, we see that the Application stop time is greater than gc time. 
Some reasons are mentioned here https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/the_unspoken_gc_times
Are there any research/analysis or any links to understand it more?

Comment: how do you know the app stop time ? can you take jstack during that delta ?

Comment: this question shouldn't be closed as offtopic

Comment: I'd think this question would be unanswerable without defining which JVM version, platform, and manufacturer

Comment: @Control that doesn't make it offtopic, you could always comment and ask for more info precisely

Comment: I'm not sure how you measured the application stop time. It would be great if you can add more details on how you did that. You can also use PMAT from IBM. Its a free jar, download it and point ur gc log, it will give a nice summary and you can get some insights

Comment: "Total time for which application threads were stopped:" in gclogs..see the blog link..he explained clearly

Comment: it would be better if you can add ur gc logs and the additional vm flags (if any) u used while debugging, also if its running server/client vm